# How can I add a gradient to my waterfall plot?

Tags: r, bar-chart, gradient, waterfall

Just started working with R and followed a tutorial to create a waterfall plot. It worked with very well when using dichotomous values:

```r
col <- ifelse(tumor_tidy_wp$zr == "YES", "#1B9E77", "#D95F02")

barplot(tumor_tidy_wp$maxchange, col=col, border="Black", space=0.5, ylim=c(-75,75),
      main = "Waterfall plot", ylab="Change from baseline (%)",
      cex.axis=1.2, cex.lab=1.4, legend.text=c("Yes","No"),
      args.legend=list(title="Uptake 89Zr on any time-point", fill=c("#1B9E77","#D95F02"), border=NA, cex=0.9)) +
      theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",angle=90))
```

[image: Waterfallplot_dichotomous]

I also have a continous scale of this value and in stead of YES/NO I would like to have a gradient instead, but I cannot get this to work. I tried to use versions of scale_fill() but failed. Is there another way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Note that `'''` (three single quotes) is not a code-fence, it's three backticks followed by a language refence, as in `\`\`\`lang-r`, all on its own line (followed by a newline). Closing the code-fence is just three backticks on their own line. Formatting code helps visualize the question for flow (text, code, text) and for making the code syntactically reasonable to read (newlines, indentation, etc).

Comment: Are you able to provide a sufficient sample of your data? The best way is with `dput`, perhaps `dput(head(tumor_tidy_wp,10))`, recognize that that will produce a smaller graph (but still likely get the point across for you to apply to your whole frame). The key to this (and the onus is completely on you) is to provide a *representative* and *unambiguous* sample of your data. Copying what `tumor_tidy_wp` looks like on the console is occasionally or often insufficient (due to whitespace, `factor`s, etc), so using `dput` is often better.

Comment: I've never seen an example that combines base graphics (`barplot`) with `ggplot2::theme` in this way. Are you certain that's doing what you intend for it to do?

Comment: Sorry not really sure how/if i can share my data. It is a relatively simple data set with 40 obs with %change frome baseline and values for uptake on PET-scan between 0 and 10 (for the gradient). I used this tutorial: https://www.r-bloggers.com/waterfall-plots-what-and-how/ . Pretty sure the ggplot2 scale_file options are probably not right but dont know if I can fix what I have or if I should start over with a ggplot graph (but could not get the bars to work with ggplot yet)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 for some context. But for "how", just run the command I gave you (`dput(head(tumor_tidy_wp,10))`) on your console, and then [edit] your question and paste it in there in a new code block.

Comment: Other options are to (1) mimick your *need* using a base dataset such as `mtcars` or `iris` (potentially with simple manipulation); or (2) create one manually, either deterministically or stochastically (use `set.seed` to give us a fixed point of randomness), and using `data.frame(...)`. Just thoughts.

Comment: I fixed it! I changed from using barplot to the ggplot  + geom_bar +  scale_fill_gradient2 like so ```ggplot(data=tumor_tidy_wp, aes(x=x, y=maxchange, fill=IA)) +  geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_fill_gradient2()```

Comment: I don't think there is an easy fix for using gradient with the basic barplot function

Comment: I think you're right (about base `barplot`), but I hadn't tried hard yet. `ggplot2` does make some types of plotting and colors easier. You still likely have a delay on self-answering, but please come back to "answer" your own question then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself by changing from using barplot to the ggplot + geom_bar + scale_fill_gradient2 like so

`ggplot(data=tumor_tidy_wp, aes(x=x, y=maxchange, fill=IA)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_fill_gradient() + theme_classic2() + expand_limits(y=c(-60, 60)) +  ylab("Change from baseline(%)")`

[Waterfall plot with gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUQX8.png)